# How to correct call C# dll methods in Python Project

Tags: c#, python

I create simple class library in C# with .Net 4.5. Build for x86 cpu. I use it in Python project. But method does not show right result when called.

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;    

    public static class SimpleLib
    {
        [DllExport("GetHelloWorld", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static string GetHelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [DllExport("ReturnMyString", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static string ReturnMyString(string value)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

And I call it in Python:

```
import ctypes
hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL("C:\\SimpleLib.dll")
print(hllDll.GetHelloWord)
```

Return this message:

> <_FuncPtr object at 0x037C0EB8>

Comment: You don't want to print it, You want to call it. what happens if You just `hllDll.GetHelloWord()`?

Comment: I try it but not working.@ntohl

Comment: Please update the question. What happens

Comment: `Hello World`, I need to write this text but Python dont write this text, if I write `print(hllDll.GetHelloWord)` command output is `<_FuncPtr object at 0x037C0EB8>`, if write `hllDll.GetHelloWord()` output `7955888`.

Comment: have you tried pythonnet? this avoids dealing with ctypes and unmanaged exports. just import clr!